# I want to pass a string to an obect

Tags: php, arrays, json, casting

I am using a widget which uses class objects as follows:

```
$p->data = array(array(array('01-Jan-2017',200),array('02-Feb-2017',210)));
```

but I want to build this array dynamically using data from a Db to extend the array structure  e.g.:

```
$wstr = "array(array(array('$varR1C1,$varR1C2),array('$varR2C1',$varR‌​2C3),array('$varR3C1‌​',$varR3C2),array(ar‌​ray('$varR4C1',$varR‌​4C2),array('$varR5C1‌​',$varR5C2),array('$‌​varR6C1',$varR6C2)))‌​;"
```

This would enable (with the widget) a Line Chart with 2 lines, each of 3 paired values. if I then try:

```
$p->data = $wstr;
```

this doesn't work. How can I cast the string to the object? I have tried JSON_encode, but this doesn't work either i.e.:

```
$p->data = substr(json_encode($wstr),1,strlen(json_encode($wstr))-2)
```

where substr gets rid of " from encode (have tried with & without!)

Comment: Have you heard of JSON?

Comment: Use JSON. It's meant to be serialized and deserialized safely. This is arbitrary code and is not something you want to blindly evaluate.

Comment: I did have a look at JSON, but when I tried the following it still failed.        $wstr = "array(array(array('01-Jan-2017',200),array('02-Feb-2017',210)))";
echo "<p>json_encode2:".substr(json_encode($wstr),1,strlen(json_encode($wstr))-2)."</p>";
i.e. echo displayed: json_encode2:array(array(array('01-Jan-2017',200),array('02-Feb-2017',210))) - json_decode returned nothing!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in your PHP code you have variables `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`, and `$var4` and you want to use these to populate the array instead of the hard-coded values in the example?

If so, why not simply

```
$p->data = array(array( array($var1, $var2), array($var3, $var4) ));
```

?

BTW, with modern syntax (PHP 5.4 and later) we prefer to use a shorter syntax for arrays (and more familiar to people coming from other languages), in which your code will look like this:

```
$p->data = [ [ [$var1, $var2], [$var3, $var4] ] ];
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit. When saying I wanted to dynamically change the array structure from the simple example, I meant to be able to extend it using data from a Db e.g. $p->data = array(array(array('$varR1C1,$varR1C2),array('$varR2C1',$varR2C3),array('$varR3C1',$varR3C2),array(array('$varR4C1',$varR4C2),array('$varR5C1',$varR5C2),array('$varR6C1',$varR6C2)));    This would enable (with the widget) a Line Chart with 2 lines, each of 3 paired values

Comment: please update the question with more details, especially an example of how you read data from the database.

Comment: P.S. I tried the format you suggested & can confirm this structure works. but I still don't know how to build this structure dynamically & cast it to the object. Thanks

Comment: I am happy with the Db axs & also that I could build a string in the format needed; the issue is how to cast the string to an object. DB axs code: $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ncbv03'); $sql = "select stdate, max(score) from hist where rid = 1 group by sdate;"; echo "<table><tr><td>When</td><td>What</td></tr>"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $when = $row["sdate"]; $what = $row["score"]; echo "<tr><td>$when</td><td>$what</td></tr>"; } } else { echo "<tr><td>No data</td><td></td></td></tr>"; } echo "</table>";

Comment: @kcoops It'll be easier to handle this if you edit your question with the new details, then I can edit my answer with what you need - writing code in the comments is really hard.